# How to find number of <ul> inside each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large file of this form [similar div's throughout]. I want to be able to select a `div`, find the number of `ul`'s in it and traverse through each of them to get value of each `li` in it.

```
<div class="experiment">
   <div class="experiment-number">5</div>
   <ul class="data-values">
         <li><div></div> 14</li>
         <li><div></div> 15</li> 
   </ul>
   <ul class="data-values">
        <li><div></div> 16</li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

I have tried looping through all experiment `div`s, then select the `ul`s, but it selects all the `ul` in the page, not only the ones under current `div`.

```
$('experiment ul').eq('$i');
```

Comment: do you want direct children ul's or indirect children also

Comment: `var count  = $('experiment > ul').length`

Comment: see this will give count of all ul in file . ie suppose i have 2 div's like above it will give 4 not 2

Comment: @user2338840: Kindly give a scenario & the expected output. For the given example, is expected output 14, 15, 16?

Comment: expected output is Exp number 5: data : 14 15 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is currently incorrect, since you're simply starting new `<div>` and `<ul>` elements rather than closing the existing ones. Ignoring that because it's trivial to fix, we'll move on to the real issue.

You need to select all of the `<div class="experiment">` elements, then iterate through them. To do that you can use the `.each()` function. It might look something like this:

```
var experiments = $('.experiment'); // all of them

experiments.each(function(i, val) { // will iterate over that list, one at a time
    var experiment = $(this); // this will be the specific div for this iteration
    console.log("Experiment: " + experiment.find('.experiment-number').text());
    // outputs the experiment number
    console.log("Experiment ULs: " + experiment.find('ul').length);
    // number of <ul> elements in this <div>
    var total = 0;
    experiment.find('ul.data-values li').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    });
    console.log("Experiment total: " + total);
    // outputs the total of the <li> elements text values
});
```

Take a look at [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ9QG/1/).

Answer (score 0):

to get all the ul inside div.experiment

```
var ul = $('.experiment').find('ul');
```

and to get all li elements inside each ul found above

```
ul.each(function(list) {
 var li = $(list).find('li');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.experiment').each(function() {
    var cnt = $(this).children('ul').length;
    $(this).find('.experiment-number').text(cnt);
});
```

Comment: Uh? What do you think `$(this).find(cnt);` does?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to work out the correct selector for each DIV.

The selector you want is:

```
".experiment"
```

Notice the `.` to denote a class selector.

This will allow you access to each DIV element. If you then want to loop though each of these, you can do so like this:

```
$(".experiment").each(function(){
   var div = $(this);

   var elementsInThisDiv = div.find("ul");
   //you now have a list of all UL elements in the current DIV only

   var numberOfElements = elementsInThisDiv.length;
   //you now have a count of UL elements belonging to this DIV only

   //you can loop the UL elements here
   $(elementsInThisDiv).each(function(){
       var ul = $(this);
       //do something with the UL element

       //like get the LI elements...
       var liElements = ul.find("li");
   });
});
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: There is also an error with your HTML, you need to close your `<ul>` elements correctly using `</ul>`

Comment: As stated in the question - and clarified in the comments - he wants an individual count *per div* not the total on the entire page.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Pretty poor question then, but I will ammend