# How to find the number of uls inside each div

Tags: php, phpquery

I have a large file of this form [similar div's throughout]. I want to be able to select a div, find the number of ul's in it and traverse through each of them to get value of each li in it.

```
<div class="experiment">
   <div class="experiment-number">5</div>
   <ul class="data-values">
         <li><div></div> 14</li>
         <li><div></div> 15</li> 
   </ul>
   <ul class="data-values">
        <li><div></div> 16</li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

wanna do it using phpQuery . already solved using jQuery here: 
[How to find number of <ul> inside each div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315691/how-to-find-number-of-ul-inside-each-div/16315816#16315816)

Comment: So what's the problem if you got it solved?

Comment: not able to do it using phpQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHPQuery but taking its doc, your jQuery code and some already existing phpQuery questions on StackOverflow, this one should work.

```
$experiments = pq('.experiment'); 

foreach($experiments as $experiment){

    echo "Experiment: ". $experiment->find('.experiment-number')->text();
    echo "Experiment ULs: " + $experiment->find('ul')->size();

    $total = 0;
    foreach($experiment->find('ul.data-values li') as $t){
        $total += (int) $t;
    }

    echo "Experiment total: " . $total;
}
```

EDIT (Seriously, just 3 errors you should have seen):

```
$experiments = pq('.experiment'); 

foreach($experiments as $experiment){
    $experiment = pq($experiment);
    echo "Experiment: ". $experiment->find('.experiment-number')->text();
    echo "Experiment ULs: " . $experiment->find('ul')->size();

    $total = 0;
    foreach($experiment->find('ul.data-values li') as $t){
        $t = pq($t);
        $total += (int) $t->text();
    }

    echo "Experiment total: " . $total;
}
```

1. a `+` becomes a `.` (one mistake I made copying your jQuery code)
2. the one you indicate in your comment.
3. `(int) $t->text();`

Comment: i wrote exactly this code earlier . it's doesn't work it should but it doesn't . plz can u check why ? it doesn't work

Comment: also u need to typecast $experiment to pq($experiment) to make it a phpQuery object. else u can't call find function

Comment: @user2338840 You should indicate PHP to show or log error. It was an easy one. `(int) $t` is not allowed since I forget `->text()`.