# how to pass full page from php to jQuery. and send some data back

Tags: php, jquery

Is there any way i can load a page in php, pass it to jQuery , extract data then send that data back to php script.

see : [How to find number of <ul> inside each div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315691/how-to-find-number-of-ul-inside-each-div)

this is lab experiment work. file is on my prof's personal site.

trying to do this using phpQuery but seem's not possible . so a possible approach is
as i mentioned above.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The workflow you are describing sounds off, like you're missing a key concept here.

Comment: So... you use PHP and Apache to send a webpage.  Then you use an AJAX call using either jQuery or an XMLHttpRequest to send data back to your Apache/ PHP server.  Profit?

Comment: Not enough detail to answer, so I'd say "probably". Where are you loading the page from? Is it on disk or on the web? I take it, since you are using jQuery, that PHP is on a web server rather than being run from the console here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like there is one extra step in the process you have described. Unless there is some reason you specifically want your PHP to load the actual file and send it to your jQuery script you would be better off just loading the page directly with jQuery.

- You could use the [`$.get()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to load the desired page.
- Once you have the content, you could insert it into your DOM in a hidden element. Now you can use normal jQuery to extract/manipulate the data.

  - You might even be able to  skip inserting the data into the DOM and just manipulate it as is.
- Once completed, send the data back to PHP using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)